# Resetting a form after ajax request with ajaxForm

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using this code to send my form using ajaxForm plugin

```
$('#donations').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSubmit: function(){
            $('#message').html('');
            $('#submit').css('color', 'red').attr("disabled", true);
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.status == 'success'){
                $('#donations').resetForm();
                $('#submit').css('color', 'white').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#message').html(response.text).delay(5000).fadeOut();
            } else {
                $('#submit').css('color', 'white').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#message').html(response.text).delay(5000).fadeOut();
            }
        }
    });
```

The submit button change and the message appear but the form don't reset.
What's the problem?

Comment: A similar question to this I believe [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653556/jquery-javascript-function-to-clear-all-the-fields-of-a-form/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981064/jquery-validate-resetform-doesnt-reset-the-onfocus-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resetForm` is an option no function

check this out [options-object](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object)

> Boolean flag indicating whether the form should be reset if the submit
>   is successful
>
> Default value: null

so i think you need to change your code into something like this:

```
$('#donations').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    resetForm: true
    //.........
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i need to clear the form only on certain response, not on success ajax.