# How to not validate form on reset()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using

```
$('#myform')[0].reset();
```

to clear HTML form fields when a clear button is clicked.  I'm also using jquery.validate.js.  So when the above runs, it triggers form validation.  All form fields with any validation then display their error messages.  How do I prevent this?

I have tried this but it didn't do anything:

```
$('#myform').removeAttr("nonvalidate");
```

Comment: How are you telling the form to be validated?

Comment: As mentioned, I'm using jquery.validate and following that pattern.  So I do $('#myform').validate({...my rules here...});

Comment: I don't know what `.reset()` is referring to for you but according to the docs it's `.resetForm()` - http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm

Comment: Check here for reset(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826381/clearing-form-input-fields-in-bootstrap

Comment: You spelled `novalidate` wrong above.  However, the `novalidate` attribute is dynamically placed there by jQuery Validate to stop HTML5 validation while you're using this plugin, so it has nothing to do with anything here.

Comment: If your "reset" button is triggering the validation, then it sounds like you've incorrectly set your reset button as a `type="submit"`.  Make it a `type="reset"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question you linked, the answer is what you want... All you have to do is capture the reset event and call [v.resetForm()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm/).

```
var v = $('form').validate(); //etc etc whatever you have here, the important part is saving "v"

$('form').on('reset',function () {
    v.resetForm();
});
```

See it working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/uuu8jerr/

Comment: If your "clear" button isn't a reset button, you'd have to change the selector from `form` to your button id, and event to `click` and add a `$('#myform').get(0).reset()` to the handler.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that removing the `novalidate` attribute has nothing to do with this... plus the OP misspelled it.